# JavaScript - compare two arrays with limited values/elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of a few numbers or strings, eg.

```
[4.3, 1.2, 4.5, 3.9]

['I', 'the', 'sheriff', 'shot']
```

The users re-arrange the elements in a specific order. For example, in an ascending order:

```
[1.2, 3.9, 4.3, 4.5]
```

and to create a valid sentence:

```
['I', 'shot', 'the', 'sheriff']
```

I have those predefined answers stored in an object. How do I compare the arrays with user generated order with the ones with correct order of elements. I have seen other answers on how to compare arrays but my question does not require a wide range of 'what if....' that other answers had. The elements are generated by the app so no unexpected input would be there, no undefined values, no empty elements, etc. Users do not input anything. They just rearrange tiles with those elements.

What's the best way to compare the arrays to determine if the users have rearranged the boxes in the right way.

My first attempt is incorrect as it always seems to be outputing 'BINGO' even if the order is incorrect:

```
if (this.props.squares === correctOrder) {
      console.log("BINGO");
    }
```

Comment: Compare the first elements, then the second elements, then the third elements, ... If all elements match -> BINGO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `every` function which all arrays have.

```
const isCorrect = this.props.squares.every((square, index) =>
  correctOrder[index] === square);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could store the wanted order in an object, where the values of the first array are the keys and ththe sorted indices the values.

For checking if in right order, just check the items array with the objects value and the actual index.

```js
var items = [1.2, 3.9, 4.3, 4.5],
    order = items.reduce((o, k, i) => (o[k] = i, o), {});
    
// check
items.every((k, i) => order[k] === i) && console.log('bingo');
```

Comment: is the comma before "o" in (o[k] = i, o). Is that so "i" is evaluated before "o" when there is an "i" value?

Comment: @Arrow, it's a comma operator and while i need to return the object, it evaluates first the assignment and returns the last part, `o`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to iterate through all the elements and compare:

```
function arraysEqual(array1, array2) {
    for(var i = array1.length; i--;) {
        if(array1[i] !== array2[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Ex:

```
arraysEqual(["I", "am", "well"], ["I", "am", "not", "well"])  // returns false
arraysEqual(["I", "am", "well"], ["I", "am", "well"])  // returns true
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `lodash`, this also could be an option.

```
_.isEqual(this.props.squares, correctOrder);
```